# How To Fix This Error [Error: Failed to find '@ionic/angular/css/display.css']

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, ionic4

When i run the operation `ionic serve` it fails to compile and gives an error code that says:

```
ERROR in ./src/global.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build- 
angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css- 
loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/
sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/global.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find '@ionic/angular/css/display.css'
in [
C:project/src
]
at resolveModule.catch.catch (project\node_modules\postcss- 
import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13)
```

This is a piece of code i tried to integrate into my own project which opens the camera to take a picture and you can either upload the picture or delete it. I tried searching for "`@ionic/angular/css/display.css`" on the internet but couldn't find a solution. I started ionic just recently so i don't understand much about it.

If anyone wants to see the code [It is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cjeqia?embed=1&file=app/tab1.page.ts) The original i took it from had the code at `home.page.ts` but i needed it at `tab1.page.ts` so the error may be born from this. Also [global.scss](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cjeqia?embed=1&file=app/global.scss)

Comment: Google docs is not the best tool to share your code. Try [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com), for example and update your question with new link. As to the error, please share your `./src/global.scss` — it might be importing absent `/display.css` file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment i updated the link and shared the global.scss file. @kos

Comment: `global.scss` is [importing](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5) a bunch of files. Ensure that you have all those files in your project on the right path. Or simply remove imports that you don't need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. copying '@ionic/angular/css/display.css' to the project solved the problem.@kos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method i used to solve the problem is importing "@ionic/angular/css/display.css". I did it manually taking it from a project where it exists and copying it to the Project which gives the error.